# How to add a user in a folder security tab

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have a shared folder on which i have given the following permissions

```
net share $NetworkSharePath  '/Grant:Administrators,FULL' '/Grant:IIS_IUSRS,FULL' | out-null
```

but this only creates user on shared permission tab I would like to add IIS user in security tab as well but dont have a clue how to do that

```
$Networkshare_Name = 'Media'
$NetworkShare_Path = 'Media=C:\_Projects\mediaFolder'
net share $NetworkSharePath  '/Grant:Administrators,FULL' '/Grant:IIS_IUSRS,FULL' | out-null


    $acl = Get-Acl $NetworkSharePath
    $rule = New-Object   
    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS","FullControl",   
    "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  

    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $NetworkSharePath $acl
```

Still no luck with this

```
    $folder = "C:\_Projects\mediaFolder"
    $acl = Get-Acl $folder
    $permission = "IIS_IUSRS","FullControl","Allow"
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $folder $acl
```

Comment: Just on my phone but the chalets you are looking for are `get-acl` and `set-acl`

Comment: @Matt is clearly on his phone, victim of autocorrect! He means `cmdlets` not chalets ;)

Comment: net share works and it adds iis user, but for some reason it not adding IIS user on security tab

Comment: Please provide evidence. The code should do what you want.

Comment: when i run this, dont get any error, its just that the folder share permission gets created but , in security TAB i cannot find IIS_IUSRS

Comment: another strange thing is i cannot manually add iis_iusrs neither in share tab or security tab

Comment: I GET THIS error when i manually try to enter IIS_IUSRS An object named "IIS_IUSRS" cannot be found, but with the script, folder share gets created but not the user security

Comment: Please double-check the group name via `lusrmgr.msc`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$acl = Get-Acl $NetworkSharePath
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $NetworkSharePath $acl
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT working for me, i have edited my question with applied solution

Comment: please clarify what is the problem

Comment: When i try to debug this, by running two lines of code i get error message cannot find drive

Comment: The problem is with my script i am able to create network share with IIS_IUSRS but i would like to add IIS_IUSRS to folder security tab as well, when i run your script i get error cannot find the drive

Comment: replace `$NetworkShare_Path = 'Media=C:\_Projects\mediaFolder'` with `$NetworkShare_Path = 'C:\_Projects\mediaFolder'` or create another variable that only contains the path

Comment: do you still get "cannot find drive" or another error? please be more specific. "still no luck" gives us absolutely no information whatsoever

Comment: hi paul when i use $NetworkShare_Path = 'C:\_Projects\mediaFolder' i get error cannot find drive c, but when i use the script written by you i get no error but at the same time, the user does not get created

Comment: Add a backslash after c:, your path is invalid